# What does it mean to declare "on a weak red suit"?

Tags: meaning, saki, reginald

In [Reginald on Tariffs](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Reginald/Reginald_on_Tariffs), Saki writes:

> [Reginald]:  I should like, for instance, a really prohibitive duty put upon the partner who **declares on a weak red suit and hopes for the best.**

What does it mean to declare "on a weak red suit"? Would "suit" refer to a piece of clothing or a playing card suit in this instance, and what is the significance of it being red? (There is also a reference to a "weak red tendency" at the conclusion of the story.)

Comment: @user14111 bridge or whist, but not Contract Bridge (invented 1925 according to Wikipedia). Saki was killed in action in 1916.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"the partner who declares on a weak red suit and hopes for the best" is certainly a reference to the card game [Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract_bridge#Scoring), specifically the early form called [Bridge Whist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_whist).

The game is played by two pairs of players, known as *partnerships*; this structure makes any player very dependent on their partner's ability, particularly in the opening stage where an unwise declaration (choice of suits) can be [expensive, particularly in the valuable red suits](https://www.pagat.com/auctionwhist/biritch.html).

Comment: Is "Red" significantly different from "Black" in this context?

Comment: If one of the red suits was declared, the points (to the trick winners) were higher than if a black suit was declared (https://www.pagat.com/auctionwhist/biritch.html).
I've added this new reference.

Comment: @mikado: You would rather declare a red suit than a black suit in Bridge Whist, all other things being equal, because the trick values are higher than red. But if you have a strong black suit and all your red suits are weak, you really, really want to ignore the trick values and declare the black suit.

Comment: And of course, it should read "higher than black" in my previous comment.